# Bash and awk - how to pass a variable to awk when doing multiline pattern maths?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I'm using `AWK` for multiline matching with patterns.
Example:

```
awk '/"ip": /,/"id": /'
```

I would like to pass an argument to AWK when I know the `ip`, so that it would return the lines that include the specified IP. Example:

```
awk '/"ip": "$IP"/,/"id": /'
```

What would be a way to do it?

I have tried:

```
awk '/"ip": "$IP"/,/"id": /'
awk '/"ip": "${IP}"/,/"id": /'
awk "/\"ip\": \"$IP\"/,/\"id'\": /"
```

I was wondering how to use this approach with patterns:

```
var="hello"; awk -v a="$var"
```

Thanks.

---

**ANSWER**

- accepted and can be found below.
- Additional details for anyone interested on how to make the matching more precise (using the variable + a string pattern). Take note that you can't wrap the variable you are using in the pattern with double quotes, it will not work even if the quotes are escapted:

  ```
  cat l.txt | awk '$0 ~ "\"ip\": \"103.6.181.43", $0 ~ "\"id\": \""'              ===> works
  cat l.txt | awk -v ipvar=103.6.181.43 '$0 ~ ipvar, $0 ~ "\"id\": \""'           ===> works
  cat l.txt | awk -v ipvar=103.6.181.43 '$0 ~ "\"ip\": \"ipvar", $0 ~ "\"id\": \""' ===> does not work
  cat l.txt | awk -v ipvar=103.6.181.43 '$0 ~ "\"ip\": \""ipvar, $0 ~ "\"id\": \""' ===> works
  ```

Finally, you can wrap / surround the parameter used in qoutes. Compare:

```
awk -v ipvar=103.6.181.43 '$0 ~ "\"ip\": \"ipvar\"", $0 ~ "\"id\": \""'  ===> will not work
awk -v ipvar=103.6.181.43 '$0 ~ "\"ip\": \""ipvar"\"", $0 ~ "\"id\": \""' ===> will work and is equivalent.
```

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add the variable within the `/ /`, because what goes there is a regular expression.

Instead, do use `$0 ~ pattern`, which gives you more freedom. After all,

```
/pattern1/,/pattern2
```

Is the same as

```
$0 ~ pattern1, $0 ~ pattern2
```

So you can use `-v` to provide the value and say:

```
awk -v var="$bash_variable" '$0~"ip: " var,$0 ~ "id: " var'
#                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                               start           end
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
ip: 23
bye
and this is
id: 23
hehe
done
$ awk -v var=23 '$0~"ip: " var,/id: /' a
ip: 23
bye
and this is
id: 23
```

Comment: Thanks, will also add some more points in the OP for reference to anyone who is lost and stumbles upon the question :)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius nice to read it worked to you. I kept my answer very simple. I guess your final solution is a bit more cumbersome because of all these double quotes that need to be escaped. Good thing you show the final version for future readers!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to expand a variable inside single quotes. Single quotes (') cause everything between them to be taken literally by bash. Try to use double-quotes instead, and see [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Regarding your question about `awk` assignments, here's an exapmle:

`awk -v foo="bar" 'foo ~ $0' <<< $'foo\nbar\nbaz'`

Output: `bar`.

Comment: I have tried the double qoutes - it's in the examples. Also, I don't understand how does the example with the assignment uses patterns - I would still like to preserve the multi-line match somehow :)

Comment: Are you trying to match `IP` sorunded by *literal* double-quotes?

Comment: Yes, the data example is like this `"ip": "127.0.0.1",` .. then a couple of lines (count of the lines is unknown, hence I need patterns) and then `"id":  "123",`

Comment: I see. Check out @fedorqui answer. It is better than mine.